# How to capture mobile notificaions using Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

Is there a way to capture notifications received on mobile using Ionic or Cordova plugin?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';

constructor(private fcm: FCM) {}

...

this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('marketing');

this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
  backend.registerToken(token);
});

this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
  if(data.wasTapped){
    console.log("Received in background");
  } else {
    console.log("Received in foreground");
  };
});

this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
  backend.registerToken(token);
});

this.fcm.unsubscribeFromTopic('marketing');
```

P.S. Detail procedure here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm